# NextJS searchParams get removes double slash for all except http://

Tags: next.js

Kind of interesting and weird behaviour I noticed while parsing search parameters using NextJS. In `/app/page` I have a server-side script with

```
export default async function MainPage({searchParams} : { searchParams: { [key: string]: string | string[] | undefined } }) {
    console.log(searchParams);
}
```

Now lets say I host on `localhost:3000` and put `http://localhost:3000?redirect=http://localhost:3001` the console will output

```
{
    redirect : 'http://localhost:3001'
}
```

As expected, however if for example I try a different redirect without `http://` for example `http://localhost:3000?redirect=myapp://auth` the output is

```
{
    redirect : 'myapp:/auth'
}
```

Removing one of the two forward slashes. The solution here naturally is to use `%2F` in place of the forward slash, but nonetheless the behaviour is odd and I wondered if anyone could explain it?

Answer (score 0):

Use this example, if you use `page router`:
Please pay attention you have to create method name like `GET, POST ...` in every function. In this method you can handle any request method easily!

```js
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function GET(request: NextRequest) {
  const { searchParams } = new URL(request.url);
  console.log(" ~ file: route.ts:10 ~ GET ~ searchParams:", searchParams);

  //...

  return NextResponse.json(searchParams);
}
```